# Objective-C: Can anyone provide a sample code on how to initialize and use NSCache?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, caching, pdf, uiwebview

I want to cache my PDF data (displayed using UIWebView) for improved app performance. I can't seem to find a working code or maybe it's just my code that doesn't work. My cache always returns NULL.

I have two viewcontrollers: NavigatePDFViewController and PDFViewController. The NavigatePDFViewController displays a list of PDF titles in which when clicked, opens a PDF file from the internet. The PDFViewController displays the PDF file.

Here are the steps I've done:

1) Added the NSCacheDelegate on my PDFViewController

2) Created an instance of NSCache like this. I created NSCache *cache in the NavigatePDFViewController.h.

```
cache = [[NSCache alloc]init];
[cache setDelegate:self];
```

3) Added an object on my cache like this. receivedData is an NSMutableData and link is an NSString.

```
[cache setObject:receivedData forKey:link];
```

4) When I check the content of my cache using the code below, it returns null.

```
[cache objectForKey:link]
```

What am I missing? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that receivedData is nil when you store it?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755902/how-to-use-nscache.

Answer (score 0):

The docs for NSCache say:

> A common data type stored in NSCache objects is an object that
>   implements the NSDiscardableContent protocol. Storing this type of
>   object in a cache has benefits, because its content can be discarded
>   when it is not needed anymore, thus saving memory.

Is it possible that your `receivedData` implements that protocol? If so, it could have been discarded and you'll have to re-create it.