# Thread safety of NSMutableDictionary access and destruction

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have an application that downloads information from a web service and caches it in memory. Specifically, my singleton cache class contains an instance variable `NSMutableDictionary *memoryDirectory` which contains all of the cached data. The data in this cache can be redownloaded easily, so when I receive a `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification` I call a method to simply invoke

```
- (void) dumpCache:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    memoryDirectory = nil;
}
```

I’m a little worried about the thread safety here. (I’ll admit I don’t know much about threads in general, much less in Cocoa’s implementation.) The cache is a mutable dictionary whose values are mutable dictionaries, so there are two levels of keys to access data. When I write to the cache I do something like this:

```
- (void) addDataToCache:(NSData *)data
                 forKey:(NSString *)
                 subkey:(NSString *)subkey
{
    if (!memoryDirectory)
        memoryDirectory = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    NSMutableDictionary *methodDictionary = [memoryDirectory objectForKey:key];
    if (!methodDictionary) {
        [memoryDirectory setObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary] forKey:key];
        methodDictionary = [memoryDirectory objectForKey:key];
    }

    [methodDictionary setObject:data forKey:subkey];
}
```

I’m worried that sometime in the middle of the process, `dumpCache:` is going to nil out the dictionary and I’m going to be left doing a bunch of `setObject:forKey:`s that don’t do anything. This isn’t fatal but you can imagine the problems that might come up if this happens while I’m *reading* the cache.

Is it sufficient to wrap all of my cache reads and writes in some kind of `@synchronized` block? If so, what should it look like? (And should my `dumpCache:` be similarly wrapped?) If not, how should I ensure that what I’m doing is safe?

Comment: Anyway, your dumpCache: is wrong. It's not enough to nil out the cache. You rather want to release it and reallocate a new one, or simply setDictionary: to an empty dictionaryy

Comment: I’m using ARC, so I don’t think I can explicitly release it, but setting it to an empty dictionary is easy enough. That would also make if(!memoryDirectory) unnecessary, since it will always at least be initialized.

Comment: You don't need to check it against not-nil. Sending messages to nil is legal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an `NSMutableDictionary`, consider using [`NSCache`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which is thread safe. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5756162/123269) for example usage. Good luck!

Comment: Somehow I hadn’t even heard of this class before. Thanks!

Comment: Be aware, NSCache is great, but sometimes deletes data for memory pressure.