How to cache CKRecords efficiently in SwiftUI
I'm building a SwiftUI social photo-sharing app that uses CloudKit, where user profiles (including a CKAsset for profile pictures) are displayed throughout the app. To reduce redundant fetching of profiles across multiple views, I’m trying to implement a cache for the profile CKRecord into a custom model. (Important for handling the CKAsset for a user’s profile picture, ensuring it’s moved from the CloudKit fileURL staging area)
Here's my current approach:
struct UserProfileModel: Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let displayUsername: String
    var profilePicture: UIImage? = nil
}

class UserProfileCache: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = UserProfileCache()
    @Published var cache: [UserProfileModel] = []
}

I'm looking for guidance on how to structure this cache efficiently. Specifically, are there any issues or problems I could be overlooking with this approach?
Thanks in advance for your help!

what type of cache do you want to use (session or permanent)?

It would be like the example code which would be just an array or dictionary or something like that for a session usage.

For this task I would use NSCahce

NSCache decides when to evict things. Which means things needed for UI could just randomly not be there when needed

You can control that behavior, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19898540/nscache-is-always-evicting-image-data-when-app-enters-background
