# Calling NSCashe doesn't work

Tags: ios, nscache

I don't know how to use `NSCashe` but I have tried it after reading this topic [How to use NSCache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755902/how-to-use-nscache/12957066#12957066) but it didn't work.

I am getting this issue **reason: '-[NSCache setObject:forKey:cost:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: indexPath)'**

Am I doing something wrong?

```
.h

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *jsonArray;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *jsonArray1;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSCache *Cache;
```

---

```
.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        NSData *response = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://kalkatawi.com/jsonTest.php"]];
        NSError *parseError = nil;
        jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&parseError];
        jsonArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        Cache = [[NSCache alloc]init];
        for(int i=0;i<[jsonArray count];i++)
        {
            NSString  * city = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"city"];

            [jsonArray1 addObject:city];
        }

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            self.title = @"İller";

            [self.mytable1 reloadData];

            jsonArray1 = [Cache objectForKey:@"indexPath"];

            [Cache setObject:jsonArray1 forKey:@"indexPath"];

        });
    });
}
```

Comment: For some reason jsonArray1 is nil in your code, try to debug and see why

Comment: Without the NSCashe code the code is working fine. I will check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are initializing jsonArray1, just before setting it up.

```
 jsonArray1 = [Cache objectForKey:@"indexPath"]; // here jsonArray1 = nil; hence remove this line and run your code again. Yo

 [Cache setObject:jsonArray1 forKey:@"indexPath"]; // hence you are setting nil value to this key "indexpath"
```

In that tutorial they are saying like

- To set a value use following line:

> [Cache setObject:jsonArray1 forKey:@"indexPath"];

- To retrieve a value use following line.  This line should be used when you want to used that cached value

> jsonArray1 = [Cache objectForKey:@"indexPath"];

In your case, just comment

> jsonArray1 = [Cache objectForKey:@"indexPath"];

line and run again. It will not give that error.

Comment: Now I have used  [Cache setObject:jsonArray1 forKey:@"indexPath"]; instead of  jsonArray1 = [Cache objectForKey:@"indexPath"]; it is working but I have called it with jsonArray1 = [Cache objectForKey:@"indexPath"]; to retrieve I can't see the difference

Comment: so it means your jsonArray1 has been assigned to indexPath key. Now whenever you want that value back in your code. You can write the other line to get objectForKey:@"indexPath" which gives, whatever value stored in it.

Comment: I have write this List = [Cache objectForKey:@"indexPath"]; //List is NSString

Comment: But in your question, JsonArray1 is an array, which we are setting to cache. Then how can you set an array and on retrieval you assign to NSString? You should have assign it to array only. Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: Try NSMutableArray *List =  [Cache objectForKey:@"indexPath"];

Comment: Now it is working... jsonArray1 = [Cache objectForKey:@"indexPath"]; - list = [jsonArray1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34682/discussion-between-luai-kalkatawi-and-mrunal)