# Which class to use in iOS for storing data in the disk?

Tags: ios, objective-c, save, plist

I am creating a calculator app similar to [this](https://vimeo.com/85879532)

The thing is I am not very sure which practice should I use to save my calculated results. I want to save only last 20 entries.

**NSCache** - [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755902/how-to-use-nscache) link says it's not a permanent cache on disk.

**NSUserDefaults** - Used for saving user preference.

**Core Data** - Seems to be an overkill in this case (do criticize if I am wrong).

**plist** - Since the data isn't much data I think this is a good choice.

However I'd like to know if there are any better practices out there which would be more professional in this case. Thanks.

Comment: I would go for a `.plist`, but if you ever need to start saving more complicated data, I would have a look at `NSKeyedArchiver`.

Comment: so there's something called as `NSKeyedArchiver`? Cool. Thanks.